# Java exception while adding image files to an existing zip file

Tags: java, filesystems

I have problems working with the FileSytem method to add an image file to a zip file. The exception is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipError: zip END header not found
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.zerror(ZipFileSystem.java:1605)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.findEND(ZipFileSystem.java:1021)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.initCEN(ZipFileSystem.java:1030)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.<init>(ZipFileSystem.java:130)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:117)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(Unknown Source)
    at Tests.main(Tests.java:71)
```

the code I use to do it is:

```
Map<String, String> zipproperties = new HashMap<>();
zipproperties.put("create", "false");
URI urizip = URI.create("jar:"+zipfile.toURI());
try(FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(urizip, zipproperties))
{
    Path entry = Paths.get(filetoadd.getAbsolutePath());
    Path Pathinzipfile = zipfs.getPath(zippath+filetoadd.getName());
    Files.move(Pathinzipfile, entry);
}
```

The Method I use to create the zip file is:

```
ZipOutputStream dest = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zippath));
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

according to [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1240011?start=0&tstart=0), the encoding of a jar should be binary, and not unicode (which makes sense...)

Comment: So Should i just change the UTF-8 to binary? another question: Should that work with an empty zip as well?

Comment: The file I am trying to add, it's an image file

Comment: regardless if it solves the problem, the encoding definitely needs to change to reflect that this is a binary file (which is true for jar and image). it is most certainly not unicode.  regarding an empty zip, I imagine that it has NO encoding.

Comment: I would try to remove the "encoding" property altogether. encoding specification is relevant for text content only (there is no such thing as "binary encoding")

Comment: That's what I thought, but even if remove the encoding. Java keeps throwing the same exception. I already tried that. I also tried making the first entry with the other method that rewrites the zip file, and then use this one but it just doesn't work. Any other thoughts?